# TwoX128 hash for rpc.state.metadata pallet names not being a prefix for storage key

Tags: polkadot-js, storage, metadata, hash

Following this tutorial: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc/

we should have that a pallet named "Members" should have prefix "0xba7fb8745735dc3be2a2c61a72c39e78" (equals to `TwoX128("Members")`)

However when accessing the value of the running chain using the polkadot-ui I get "0x2ce461329fdf4be12bce01afc0af09bc"

##### Details

- pallet name from metadata is obtained from `api.rpc.state.getMetadata()` with `api` being of type `ApiPromise`
- twox128 is computed via `@polkadot/util-crypto` `xxhashAsHex`

Answer (score 1):

After some inspection for the `api.rpc.state.getMetadata(..)` in the latest version of the `MetadataV*` type (currently `MetadataV14`) you can get the string used for the prefix from `metadata.asLatest.pallets.storage.unwrap().prefix.toString()` (clearly provided that `metadata.asLatest.pallets.storage` is not `None`)